# Consume ASP.NET WebService In php and return soap error

Tags: php, asp.net, web-services

i am trying to calling .net webservice in php
below is my code.

```
<?php
    $client = new SoapClient("http://test.etech.net/PanelIntegration/PanelIntegration.asmx?wsdl");

         <?php  
         $sh_param = array( 
                            'Username'    =>    'IntegratorLPI', 
                            'Password'    =>    'password531'); 
                $headers = new SoapHeader('http://wms.etech.net/', 'UserCredentials', $sh_param);
                 $client->__setSoapHeaders($headers);   



                $params = array('CustomerName' => 'Mr Smith','ContactMobileNo' => '01237 376347',
                                'AddressLine1' => '33 Amblecote Road',
                                'AddressTown' => 'Cambridgeshire',
                                'AddressPostCode' => 'NW23 6TR',
                                'VendorAddressLine1' => '80 Norton Road',
                                'VendorAddressTown' => 'Hickley ',
                                'VendorAddressCounty' => 'Cambridgeshire',
                                'VendorAddressPostCode' => 'NW23 2AQ',
                                'RegionalOfficeID' => '3',
                                'ExternalNotes' => 'Case Accepted',
                                'UPRN' => '',
                                'InstructionTypeID' => '2',
                                'PropertyTypeID' => '11',
                                'PropertyTenure' => '2',
                                'SurveyorID' => '23',
                                'RRN' => '0240-9002-0391-3520-0020',
                                'NewInstruction'=> 'true',
                                'StatusID' => '1'
                                );
                $result = $client->__soapCall("UpdateInstruction", $params );

                print_r(    $result);

    ?>
```

i have got this error
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in C:\xampp\htdocs\test2.php:33 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test2.php(33): SoapClient->__soapCall('UpdateInstructi...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test2.php on line 33

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to send something like:

```
 $result = $client->__soapCall("UpdateInstruction", array('Instruction' => $params );
```

Where Instruction is the name of the object that you are passing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a `NullReferenceException` was thrown on the server side.  So, it's a matter of the parameters to whatever function is occurring on the server side generating that error.

Regardless of why, per best practices, this is an error in the .NET service.  The `NullReferenceException` should really be replaced with something more specific.

Can you get in touch with whomever wrote the service to get more information to troubleshoot?  It's quite possible that you have a parameter misnamed in your `$params` array, but you're probably going to need some help from the service writer.

Comment: well Andrew thanks your reply but this web service working fine when i have called in .net with same parameter.any other way to call this service in php. thanks